# Radeon rx570 driver

Tags: drivers, radeon, gpu

So I have been with ubuntu for the past 6 years now, on my laptop. This os never dissapointed me. Now I have decided to have my desktop running Ubuntu since windows 7 will not be supported.

My pc: Dell optiplex 7010 i5
GPU    1: Gigabyte Radeon rx570 2: Gt 710.

Problem: I have 3 monitors. One with the Gigabyte, two with the nvidia.

Everything works perfectly with the two monitors that are pluged into the nvidia card. However, the Radeon GPU is not working properly with Ubuntu. The screen acts funny, fans are spinning non stop. I tried to install the gpu pro driver,it was intalled succesfully but now I have black screen. Is there any way I could make the Radeon ex570 gpu wörk with ubuntu?

Thank you for any support!